# Shuffle LiveData<List<Item>> from Room Database on App Open

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

I have a RecyclerView which displays `LiveData<List<Item>>` returned from a Room Database. Everything works fine, however, the Item order needs to be randomized every time the app is open for a more dynamic feel.

The Item's are displayed in `AllItemFragment`. When an item is clicked, it will be added to the users favourites. This will then add the Item to the `FavouriteFragment`.

Ordering the `SQL query` by `RANDOM()` would be called every time the data is changed (i.e. when an item is clicked) and therefore wont work.

`List.shuffle` cannot be called on `LiveData` object for obvious reasons.

Data is retrieved in the following format:

`DAO -> Repository -> SharedViewholder -> Fragment -> Adapter`

DAO

```
@Query("SELECT * from items_table")
fun getAllItems(): LiveData<MutableList<Item>>
```

Repository

```
val mItemList: LiveData<MutableList<Item>> = itemDoa.getAllItems()
```

SharedViewHolder

```
init {
        repository = ItemRepository(itemDao)
        itemList = repository.mItemList
}

fun getItems(): LiveData<MutableList<Item>> {
        return itemList
}
```

Fragment

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        mSharedViewModel = activity?.run {
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
        } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
        mSharedViewModel.getItems().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { item ->
            // Update the UI
            item.let { mAdapter.setItems(it!!) }
        })
}
```

Adapter

```
internal fun setItems(items: MutableList<Item>) {
        val diffCallback = ItemDiffCallback(this.mItems, items)
        val diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffCallback)
        this.mItems.clear()
        this.mItems.addAll(items)
        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }
```

**EDIT**

Using `switchMap()` still shuffles the entire list when a user presses the favourite button

```
fun getItems(): LiveData<MutableList<Item>> {
        return Transformations.switchMap(mItemList) { list ->
            val newLiveData = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Item>>()
            val newList = list.toMutableList()
            Collections.shuffle(newList)
            newLiveData.setValue(newList)
            return@switchMap newLiveData }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `.shuffled()` with seeded `Random` instance. The idea is to randomize the list, but the randomize in the same way, until the process dies and the user relaunches the app to generate a new seed.

Repository

```
private val seed = System.currentTimeMillis()
val mItemList: LiveData<MutableList<Item>> = Transformations.map(itemDoa.getAllItems()) {
    it.shuffled(Random(seed))
}
```

The seed must be consistent throughout the application's process. I think keeping the seed in the repository is pretty safe, assuming that your repository is implemented in a singleton pattern. If it is not the case, just find yourself a singleton object and cache the seed.

Comment: This is the solution that worked. Much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [`switchMap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations.html#switchmap) transformation operator on `LiveData`.

```
return liveData.switchMap(list -> {
    var newLiveData = LiveData<MutableList<Item>>()
    var newList = list.toMutableList()
    Collections.shuffle(newList)
    newLiveData.setValue(newList)
    return newLiveData
})
```

For creating new LiveData you can use `LiveData` constructor and `setValue(T value)` method.
As value you can set `Collections.shuffle(list)`

You could use it in your repository or in the view model.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding but this gives the same result. The list is shuffled everytime the favourite button is pressed. I did have to make a few changes as LiveData doesn't expose setValue. I updated th OP with the switchMap implementation used.

Comment: @Muzzle Oh, I misunderstood your problem, sorry about that. I thought you're trying just randomize the array.